# Close button in respond_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Whenever I enter, update or delete something in a view, a message will appear informing me that this operation has been successful, but it only exits when I go to a new page. I would like to know how to insert a button so that this message adds up. I am currently sending the department_controller.rb:

```
  def edit
  end

  # POST /departments
  # POST /departments.json
  def create
    @department = Department.new(department_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @department.save
        format.html { redirect_to @department, notice: 'Departamento criado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @department }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @department.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /departments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /departments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @department.update(department_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @department, notice: 'Departamento atualizado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @department }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @department.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you post your respective views, it seems like you only have the code to show the alert in one page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **HTML only** as response, make sure that ERB files where you want to show the **notice** has the below HTML tag at the top of your page, as it seems you don't have this tag in other pages:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example

```
format.html { redirect_to @department, notice: 'Departamento criado com sucesso.' }
```

`notice:` uses `flash` under the covers. `flash` messages are stored in the session but go away after they're rendered. If you want these messages to persist, you'll have to avoid using flash. Storing them in the session may be an option, but space in the session is very limited. Here's an example of messages that would persist until the session is reset, which would probably be whenever the user logged out.

```
# in controller action
session[:messages] ||= []
session[:messages] << 'Departamento criado com sucesso.'

# in view
<%= session[:messages] %>
```

It sounds like you want to be able to dismiss (close?) these messages one-by-one. That would imply creating a controller action to handle that behavior:

```
# in config/routes.rb
resources :messages, only: :delete

# in app/controller/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController
  def destroy
    session[:messages]&.delete_at(params[:id])
    redirect_to :back
  end
end

# In your layout i.e. app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= session[:messages]&.each_with_index do |message, i| %>
  <%= message %>
  <%= link_to 'X', message_path(i), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```